# AES Illegal Key Size error occuring only in command line but not in IDE

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, aes, jce

I require a higher key size for AES (192-bit) and installed JCE as per instructions on the site.

The strange thing is, while running my program in Netbeans, the encryption and decryption works perfectly.

But if I compile and run from command line, it would throw "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size"

Is there something else I need to add to the compile command? 
My compile command is just the regular one, which looks something like this
javac -d . -cp . DC\src\dc\Main.java DC\src\share\AES.java

Comment: Add to the main method a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"))` to work out what's different between the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your IDE uses a JDK, the commandline uses the standard JRE. You must install JCE in both directories.

Maybe look up the active Java in the PATH and double check the JCE there.

Comment: You're right! Didn't know I had to install twice. It works now. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your IDE is using the same JRE as your command line?